# Current situation for Indian travellers visiting Georgia? (2019/2020)

Tags: indian-citizens, georgia-country

There have been a lot of reports about Georgian immigration authorities [deporting Indian travelers even though all paperwork was in order](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Georgia-deporting-Indians). In fact, if I'm not wrong, an Indian Embassy even issued an advisory against travel to Georgia.

What is the situation in 2019/2020? Any on-ground reports from Georgians (or Indian who recently visited Georgia)? And what did we Indians do to deserve this in the first place?

Comment: Everything I read online indicated that the problem was specifically with e-visas. That might be why there is a new e-visa procedure for Georgia now.

Comment: That is what I suspect as well, but want to be a little more certain about this before planning my travel.